# How to push key/values in object?

Tags: javascript

***I'm just calling function with argument value is an Object and check if value is available into object push that's value into created object.***

this is my code:
calling function here:

```
profile({"first_name":'kaushik', "last_name":'makwana'});
```

declare function here:

```
function profile(profileInfo){
    profileInfo = JSON.stringify(profileInfo);
    var profileData  = JSON.parse(profileInfo);
    var first_name   = profileData.first_name;
    var last_name    = profileData.last_name;
    var email        = profileData.email;
    var message      = profileData.message;

    var data = {};
    if(typeof first_name != 'undefined'){
        data['first_name'] = first_name;
    }
    else if(typeof last_name != 'undefined'){
        data['last_name'] = last_name;
    }
    else if(typeof email != 'undefined'){
        data['email'] = email;

    }
    else if(typeof message != 'undefined'){
        data['message'] = message;

    }
    console.log(data);
 }
```

its display like:

```
  Object({"first_name" : kaushik});
```

Comment: i want to output like {"first_name" : "kaiushik" , "last_name" : "makwana"}

Comment: @OP, If form value is not inputted by user, it will be `''` not `undefined`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is you are using if and else if

So once

```
if(typeof first_name != 'undefined'){
        data['first_name'] = first_name;
    }
```

this condition is true it will ignore other conditions.
so use it like

```
function profile(profileInfo){
    profileInfo = JSON.stringify(profileInfo);
    var profileData  = JSON.parse(profileInfo);
    var first_name   = profileData.first_name;
    var last_name    = profileData.last_name;
    var email        = profileData.email;
    var message      = profileData.message;

    var data = {};

    if(typeof first_name != 'undefined'){
        data['first_name'] = first_name;
    }
    if(typeof last_name != 'undefined'){
        data['last_name'] = last_name;
    }
    if(typeof email != 'undefined'){
        data['email'] = email;

    }
    if(typeof message != 'undefined'){
        data['message'] = message;

    }
    console.log(data);
 }
profile({"first_name":'kaushik', "last_name":'makwana'});
```

I hope it will help

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that only one body of `if - else if - else` conditional is run.

So you don't want to have a bunch of `else if` but separated `if`s

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> profileInfo = JSON.stringify(profileInfo);
> var profileData  = JSON.parse(profileInfo);
> ```

This is completely useless and superfluous. Why JSON encode to then decode it again? It doesn't do anything of use here.

> ```
> var first_name   = profileData.first_name;
> ```

This is also rather superfluous. Why assign each property to an individual variable? You can use the property directly as is.

> ```
> if(typeof first_name != 'undefined')
> ```

This is *questionable* and depends on what exactly you expect to be a valid value. If you accept `0` as a valid first name, then you indeed need to check for `undefined`. However, if any *falsey* value should be rejected, just check for `== false`. The typical idiom in Javascript is:

```
a = a || b;
```

This keeps `a` if `a` is *truthy*, else uses `b`.

---

I'd suggest this:

```
function profile(profileInfo) {
    var data = {
        first_name: profileInfo.first_name || null,
        last_name: profileInfo.last_name || null,
        email: profileInfo.email || null,
        message: profileInfo.message || null,
    };
    console.log(data);
}
```

Note that this means `data` will always have all properties, in opposition to what you're doing now. But really, what *are* you doing?! You're just recreating the same object again. This code here essentially does the same thing:

```
function profile(profileInfo) {
    var data = profileInfo;
    console.log(data);
}
```

If you're interested in cloning the object so as to break any reference to the original, see [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/122102/476). But that doesn't necessarily seem to be what you really need.

If you want to filter `profileInfo` to some defined sub-set (i.e. you want to remove all properties except a few expected ones):

```
function profile(profileInfo) {
    var data = {};
    for (var prop in profileInfo) {
        if (['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'message'].indexOf(prop) > -1) {
            data[prop] = profileInfo[prop];
        }
    }
    console.log(data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

remove unnecessory if-else.

```
function profile(profileInfo) {

            profileInfo = JSON.stringify(profileInfo);
            var profileData = JSON.parse(profileInfo);
            var first_name = profileData.first_name;
            var last_name = profileData.last_name;
            var email = profileData.email;
            var message = profileData.message;

            var data = {};

            if (typeof first_name != 'undefined') {
                data['first_name'] = first_name;
            } 
            if (typeof last_name != 'undefined') {
                data['last_name'] = last_name;
            }  
            if (typeof email != 'undefined') {
                data['email'] = email;

            } 
           if (typeof message != 'undefined') {
                data['message'] = message;

            }
            console.log(data);
        }
```

If you have array then you can do it in this way also.

```
var data = [];
        function profile(profileInfo) { 

             data.push(profileInfo);

             console.log(data);
        }


        profile({
            "first_name": 'kaushik',
            "last_name": 'makwana'
        });

        profile({
            "first_name": 'kaushik111',
            "last_name": 'makwana111'
        });
```